# Access 2013 Dlookup issue

Tags: filtered-lookup

good morning all
I usually find the answer to my queries already on here but this one has me stumped. I have 3 tables, 
`area` containing Area and Region, `Phones` comtaining phone number and IMSI (SIM number) and a `log` containing all 4 fields.
I've put in a `Dlookup` (as found on this site) on the log and although it works the first time the event is triggered it allways comes up with the wrong value. It's probably something stupid and simple, it's years since I used Access and that was probably Access 2007 or something.

Hope you can help. I have created a cut down test version but not sure how to add it to the question.

The VB code is here

```
Private Sub Area_Change() 
Dim FoundRegion As String 
FoundRegion = DLookup("[Region]", "[Area]", "'[Area]![Area]=[Area]'") 
Me.Region = FoundRegion 
End Sub 
Private Sub Phone_Number_AfterUpdate() 
Dim FoundIMSI As Double 
FoundIMSI = DLookup("[IMSI ]", "[phones]", "'[phones]![Phone Number]=[Phone Number]'") 
Me.IMSI = FoundIMSI 
End Sub
```

not sure how to add the database

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow take a look about how to add questions properly (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should provide some code in order to get an accurate answer ;)

Comment: thank you,  The VB code is here
    
Private Sub Area_Change()
    Dim FoundRegion As String
    FoundRegion = DLookup("[Region]", "[Area]", "'[Area]![Area]=[Area]'")
    Me.Region = FoundRegion
End Sub

Private Sub Phone_Number_AfterUpdate()
    Dim FoundIMSI As Double
    FoundIMSI = DLookup("[IMSI  ]", "[phones]", "'[phones]![Phone Number]=[Phone Number]'")
    Me.IMSI = FoundIMSI
End Sub

not sure how to add the database

Comment: It's better if you add it on the question because you can add format and it will improve the readability. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub Area_Change()
    Dim FoundRegion As String
    FoundRegion = DLookup("[Region]", "[Area]", "'[Area]![Area]=[Area]'")
    Me.Region = FoundRegion
End Sub

Private Sub Phone_Number_AfterUpdate()
    Dim FoundIMSI As Double
    FoundIMSI = DLookup("[IMSI  ]", "[phones]", "'[phones]![Phone Number]=[Phone Number]'")
    Me.IMSI = FoundIMSI
End Sub

Comment: this is the macros I am using, does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?